# setting python path in virtual env

Tags: python, python-venv

I have the following directory structure:

```
~
|-- test
     |-- foo.py
```

I was able to run `foo.py` as `python test/foo.py` or `python -m test.foo` in the normal command line. But once I started a venv in `~` the former still works but the latter no longer works (python complains about "No module named test.foo"). Did I set my python path incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that python is not recognizing test.foo as a module. To fix is simply add an empty file called `__init__.py` into the test directory.

Then you should be able to run it like so `python -m test.foo`

Comment: that works! but why was that not needed when I was running in the non virtual env?

Comment: Probably because python -m only works with modules. I'd have to look it up though